# pointer to ArrayList in other class

Tags: java, arraylist, declaration

In class Browser I have the field

```
   private ArrayList<WineCase> basket;
```

and also I have created the ArrayList within the constructor:

```
   basket = new ArrayList<WineCase>();
```

In class Website I have to access this ArrayList. When I try to compile this for-each header:

```
 for(WineCase wineCase : basket)
```

the error is that "variable basket is not declared". How to declare the ArrayList from Browser class ?

Comment: You need to pass it as a parameter somewhere.  You can then store it in a private field.

Comment: I think you sohuld make the ArrayList static, and Public. As well to access it you should use Browser.basket or something. Even though this way is a little unprofessional, it may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `basket` as `private` in `Browser`, so you can't access it directly.  That's good; it's encapsulated.

Create a "getter" method in `Browser` to access it:

```
public ArrayList<WineCase> getWineCases() {
    return basket;
}
```

Of course, you'll still need an instance of a `Browser` on which to call `getWineCase`.  Then you can just call the method:

```
for(WineCase wineCase : aBrowser.getWineCases())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access private instance variable belong to another class. You need to declare the `basket` in `Website` class or, make the `basket` as a public instance variable (not recommanded, better to access through a getter method), and access it with an instance of `Browser` class from `Website` class.

```
pulic ArrayList<WineCase> basket; //in Browser class
```

or

```
private ArrayList<WineCase> basket; //in Browser class

public ArrayList<WineCase> getBasket() {} // in Browser class
```

and

```
for(WineCase wineCase : browserInstance.basket) // in Website class
```

Comment: Or create a getter method in class `Browser` that returns `basket`.